# why doesn't this work even though the strings match

Tags: python, file, filereader

```
games=[]

file=open("egames.txt",'r')
for game in file:
    games.append(game)
file.close()

print("All games made by Rockstar Games")
for game in games:
    currentline=game.split(",")
    publisher=currentline[5]
    if publisher=="Rockstar Games":
        print(currentline[0],currentline[1])
```

I dont get any errors i just get nothing being printed] with Rockstar Games.[The actual Text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7X0y.png)

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you could provide the text file using pastebin: https://pastebin.com

Comment: Posting an input file as an image isn't very useful.

Comment: (for many reasons: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4669135)

Answer (score 3):

Lines read from a file iterator end with newline characters. You should strip them as part of the normalization:

```
for game in file:
    games.append(game.rstrip())
```

Comment: Glad to be of help. Can you mark this answer as accepted if you find it to be correct? (Click on the grey check mark next to the answer.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the issue is the trailing newline characters, which are invisible to your eye. Try stripping off any white space:

```
publisher = currentline[5].strip()
```